# declare instance variable in category

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I defined a category for NSDictionary

**NSDictionary+AddMyFunc.m**

```
// Compiler error: expected identifier or '('
@implementation NSDictionary (AddMyFunc) { 
    NSInteger myNum;
}

- (void)myFunc {
  //Compiler error: use of undeclared identifier 'myNum'
  myNum = //some operation
}

@end
```

I want to define a **instance variable** `myNum`, I did it in above way, but I got compiler errors showing above.
Why I get those errors, how to get rid of them?

Comment: Why downvote? I can't find a answer on internet, so I ask here, what is wrong with that? There might be other people have the same confusion like me. Explanation on question is better than downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can add properties to category using associated object

```
#import <objc/runtime.h> 

static const void *ImageTagKey = &ImageTagKey;

@implementation UIImage (Tagged)

- (void)setTag:(NSSting *)tag
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, ImageTagKey, tag, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}

- (NSString *)tag
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, ImageTagKey);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use *class extension* feature of injecting instance variables with a *category*, where this feature is not available. Class extensions are more powerful than categories, but they cannot be added to other people's classes.

In order to add a property that acts like an instance variable to your category, use associated objects, like this:

```
@interface NSDictionary (AddMyFunc)
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *myNum;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
NSString * const kMyNumKey = @"MyNumKey";

@implementation NSDictionary (AddMyFunc)

- (void)setMyNum:(NSNumber*)n {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kMyNumKey, n, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}

- (NSNumber*)myNum {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kMyNumKey);
}

@end
```

This property is not a true instance variable, so you cannot access it using the pointer `->` syntax. However, both dot syntax and square bracket syntax are available.

Comment: Minor nitpick. Your solution doesn't let you add an instance variable. It lets you add a property.

Comment: @rmaddy That's a fair observation, I edited to make it clear that it's a property, not a true instance variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables are not supported in categories.  This makes sense if you know what an instance actually is, and how storage is allocated.

Because categories may be loaded in any order, there would be no way for the compiler and linker to know what the address of the instance variable would be.

If you need to mimic properties, use associated objects.